# Windows Server 2012 TCP/IP Port Exhaustion Caused by spoolsv.exe

Tags: print-server

I have a server 2012 installation that is hosting all of our printers for our school district. as well as the google cloud print service so that our chromebooks can print. Over the last couple months I have noticed that the server will just stop allowing end users to print and printers will "go offline" I RDP into the server and run netstat -anob as admin and it will list all the Ports that are ESTABLISHED which normally caps at about 65k. The service that opened them all is spoolsv.exe and it will display what PID it has at at that time. It is now to the point where I have to go in and restart the print spooler several times a day to clear out the ports and then everthing works 100% again.

Has anyone else had this problem? Is there any way I can avoid it or figure out whats causing it. I have read it may be a poorly written driver but I have no way of telling what printer the user printed to in order to open that port. and removing and re-adding the drivers isn't an option as it serves 4 schools ad they "NEED" to print!

Comment: What ip address does netstat show the spooler service connected to?  Is it for every printer or only one/some of them?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean. it shows two different ways one is [spoolsv.exe] TCP 10.1.0.21:49159 (local address) 10.3.100.193 (foreign address) ESTABLISHED(port status) 1100 (PID). The other just shows [Spoolsv.exe] UDP 0.0.0.0:xxxx *:* 1100